# How to connect Intellij to a remote wildfly server

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

I have a clean wildfly 8.1 installation on a remote server. Note that this remote server is a virtual box server created with vagrant.

Now i want to connect IntelliJ using a remote JBoss server.

First i have created a dummy user, with username/password: jboss/jboss

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./add-user.sh 

What type of user do you wish to add? 
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties) 
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): a

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ManagementRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : jboss
Password recommendations are listed below. To modify these restrictions edit the add-user.properties configuration file.
 - The password should not be one of the following restricted values {root, admin, administrator}
 - The password should contain at least 8 characters, 1 alphabetic character(s), 1 digit(s), 1 non-alphanumeric symbol(s)
 - The password should be different from the username
Password : 
JBAS015269: Password must have at least 8 characters!
Are you sure you want to use the password entered yes/no? yes
Re-enter Password : 
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]: 
About to add user 'jboss' for realm 'ManagementRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Added user 'jboss' to file '/opt/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties'
Added user 'jboss' to file '/opt/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/domain/configuration/mgmt-users.properties'
Added user 'jboss' with groups  to file '/opt/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties'
Added user 'jboss' with groups  to file '/opt/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/domain/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process? 
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="amJvc3M=" />
```

Then i started the wildfly server using the following command:

```
./standalone.sh -bmanagement=192.168.33.10 -b 192.168.33.10
```

These are my remote JBoss server settings in IntelliJ:

```
Jboss server settings:
Management Port: 9999
username: jboss
password: jboss

remote connection settings:
host: 192.169.33.10
port: 9999
```

But i get the following error:

```
Error running mythings-vagrant
Unable to connect to the 192.168.33.10:9999, reason:
com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://192.168.33.10:9999. The connection failed
```

Answer (score 5):

WildFly now uses port 9990 for it's default management port. There was some [release notes](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/11/WildFly8-Final-Released/#_port_reduction) about the port reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Check you firewall on the remote machine,
I can deploy to a remove vm in Azure with intelliJ (when i want to) without issue.