# What is the most efficient/automated way to remote debug a SOA application running on Linux VM from Windows desktop through IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ob3h.png)[image]
I want to build and remote debug an SOA based CDI java application running on a Linux VM from Windows desktop using IntelliJ Idea. What is the most efficient way to do this so that it relieves me from manually transferring (sftp) the application, set up for remote debugging, etc?

I don't want to exit my IDE but would like to debug the application on a remote machine by modifying the app repeatedly. I would like to see the results in the IDE console window/web browser as applicable.

I used the remote debugging option in Intellij IDE, In run/debug configuration option I used Listen to remote JVM and start the debug in IntellijIDE.
I then run the following command in VM Linux:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005  com.intel.podm.rest.RequestValidationFilter
```

[image]
In Intellij IDE the command line arguments are dynamically updating to

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=DESKTOP-52V2CBR:5005,suspend=y,onthrow=,onuncaught=

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392922/104891) help?

Comment: If am running the command from VM Linux ,java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005  com.intel.podm.rest.RequestValidationFilter  ,Its displaying Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Error: Could not find or load main class com.intel.podm.rest.RequestValidationFilter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the details how to make a working jar with the main class and the dependencies.

Comment: I created a artifact ,infact the jar created in IntelliJ under .idea --> artifacts --> SW_jar.xml,wheni imported to linux the jar is in form of .xml format,need a jar file to debug from linux.

Comment: Artifact is stored in the output directory, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Comment: Finally i created jar by following file-> project structure->artifact->choosing MANIFEST under resources file ,as i followed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly for building jar,finally the jar created and i start to debug in Intellij and my Java application running in Ubuntu.After running the below command the result was  java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787 -jar SW.jar
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
Error: Could not find or load main class com.test    still am getting another error

Comment: Make sure the main class is specified correctly in the jar manifest.

Comment: error returning for com.test while creating a jar i selected all modules and libraries ,still it is checking for com.test. yes the main class is included in module

Comment: Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get further help if you can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: a partial fix done by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190769/how-to-connect-intellij-to-a-remote-wildfly-server,and created a gradle configuration to debug,perhaps when debug clicks all the threads are initiating and loading ,doesnt hitting any code.Do any body knows how to create a "Run/Remote" Configuration IntellIj,please let  me know

Comment: Do any body knows how to create a "Run/Remote" Configuration IntellIj,please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by opening SSH on Linux and remote debug in Intellij,and port number changes in standalone.sh script as project is based on wildfly server builded in gradle build environment.
Step 1: open a remote debug
step 2:  ssh targetMachine@10.10.10.10 –L 8888:127.0.0.1:8787

If your application is in different machine try to create SSH tunnel for example:
ssh targetMachine@10.10.10.10 –L 8888:127.0.0.1:8787
Where targetMachine@10.10.10.10 is target user and address.
8888 is the local port where is IDE
8787 is debbuger port in the targetMachine (you can check that port in standalone.sh script)